# How can I record the entire screen outside of my Flutter app or control a specific area for recording, including sound?

Tags: flutter, package, screen, screen-recording, multiple-records

I'm working on a Flutter app and I need to implement screen recording functionality. However, I'm facing challenges with recording the entire screen outside of my Flutter app or controlling a specific area for recording while ensuring that all features, including sound, are captured.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Investigated Flutter packages: I've searched for Flutter packages that offer screen recording capabilities, but most of them seem to be limited to recording within the app itself.

Explored platform-specific solutions: I've looked into native Android and iOS APIs for screen recording, but I'm unsure how to integrate them with my Flutter app.

Considered third-party libraries: I've explored third-party libraries that offer screen recording features, but I'm not sure how to integrate them with my Flutter app and whether they support recording the entire screen or specific areas.

Based on the above, I have the following questions:

Is it possible to record the entire screen outside of my Flutter app using Flutter or platform-specific APIs?

If not, how can I control a specific area for recording while ensuring that all features, including sound, are captured?

Are there any Flutter packages or third-party libraries that support these functionalities, and if so, how can I integrate them into my Flutter app?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!